# Не могу установить данные которые загружаю в doInBackground

Tags: android

Всем привет. На стековерфлоу меня проигнорили или не могут понять что хочу. Вобщем пытаюсь сделать загрузчик картинок. использую пример android-universal-image-loader. Все отлично работает и загружает если я использую ссылки прописанные в коде. тоесть

```
public final class Constants {

    public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
            "первая ссылка",
            "вторая ссылка",
            "третья ссылка",
            ..... и так далее.....
    }
    }
а потом в

 public class ImageGridActivity extends AbsListViewBaseActivity {
        static  String[] imageUrls;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
    imageUrls = Constants.IMAGES;// тут присваиваю массиву значения из класса Constants
    ......
```

//и скармливаю свой массив ссылок imageLoader'у

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {...}
```

если я делаю все так как описал выше то все работает. но мне нужно парсить ссылки а не использовать готовые, поэтому я создал поток в котором вытаскиваю нужные ссылки и пытаюсь передать их в главный поток для дальнейшей передачи в адаптер. сделал я это так

мой поток:

```
interface IOnParseResult {
    void onDone(ArrayList<String> data);

}

public final class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Elements title;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    IOnParseResult onParseResult;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                data = new ArrayList<String>();
                doc = Jsoup.connect(arg[0]).get();
                title = doc.select("div");
                String m;
                for (Element titles : title) {
                    if (titles.children().hasClass("btl")){
                    m = titles.select("img").attr("abs:src");
                    data.add(m);
                    }
```

// если тут я выведу data в лог то выводятся нужные мне ссылки так как мне нужно. следовательно data содержит то что мне нужно. 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

```
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

      if (onParseResult == null) return;

     onParseResult.onDone(data);
}

public void setOnParseResult(IOnParseResult onParseResult) {
    this.onParseResult = onParseResult;
}
```

}

главный класс:

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends AbsListViewBaseActivity {
    static  String[] imageUrls = null;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    NewThread t;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
        t = new NewThread();
        t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
             @Override
             public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                 imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
                 //тут поидеии imageUrls должен стать равным нужным мне сылкам
             }
         });
         t.execute("http://www.kartinki24.ru/kartinki/3d/");
         Log.d("HZ", imageUrls[0]);//в логе выводится нужная мне ссылка, но уже после ошибки. я думаю что ошибка изза того что данные ворачиваются уже после того как адаптер их устанавливает. но как исправить не знаю((((((( помогите пожалуйста!
```

вот лог ошибки:

```
04-05 12:05:43.533: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.SimpleFromEclipse/com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageGridActivity.java:90)
        at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:131)
        at com.example.SimpleFromEclipse.ImageGridActivity.onCreate(ImageGridActivity.java:71)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        ... 11 more
```

вопрос решен всем спасибо))) установил setAdapter() в

```
 t.setOnParseResult(new IOnParseResult() {
             @Override
             public void onDone(ArrayList<String> data) {
                 imageUrls = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
                 ((GridView)listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
             }
         });
         t.execute("http://www.kartinki24.ru/kartinki/3d/");
```

Comment: У вас в адаптер передан null, поэтому вылетает такая ошибка.
Покажите как вы "скармливаете" ему данные и в какой момент.

Answer (score 1):

Замените static  String[] imageUrls = null; на static  String[] imageUrls = {};